# Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.exe -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];

Tags: python, node.js, ionic-framework, sass, node-sass

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.exe -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\abdul\\Desktop\\eventsja-master\\node_modules\\node-gyp\
```

expecting a dependencies deperecation but still no idea

Comment: In the traceback `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?`

Comment: You're trying to run a Python 2.x command in Python 3.x.